# A strange result of english analyzer which is not the same as elasticsearch definitive guide said

Tags: elasticsearch

The example in [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_controlling_analysis.html#_controlling_analysis) says using `GET /my_index/_analyze` to analyze the word `Foxes` will return the term `fox`.
But in my case, I found the result is still `foxes`.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/my_type?pretty
```

Mapping:

```
{
  "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "my_type" : {
        "properties" : {
          "english_title" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "english"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Test**:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?pretty -d '
{
  "field": "my_type.english_title",   
  "text": "Foxes"
}
'
```

Response:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "foxes",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

When I used GET /_analyze, the result was the term `fox`.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty -d '
{
  "analyzer": "english",   
  "text": "Foxes"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "fox",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it a mistake in the tutorial? `GET /my_index/_analyze` this method can't get the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All make perfect sense.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?pretty -d '
{
  "field": "my_type.english_title",   
  "text": "Foxes"
}
```

You are sending to analyze field **my_type.english_title** which is missing because. So my **type.** should be removed

try

```
 curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?pretty -d '
    {
      "field": "english_title",   
      "text": "Foxes"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You're correct. Because I referred to a native language version of this tutorial. I didn't recognize the mistake in that version.

Comment: By the way you can do dot if you have nested object